# can i check a tcpclient is disposed or not in tcp ip in c#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

i want create a server for tcp/ip

i have this code :

```
if (myTcpClient.Available == 0)
{
}
```

when client has disposed i receive this error:

```
System.Object Disposed Exception: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
```

can i check client is disposed or not? thank you can i check client is disposed or not? thank you can i check client is disposed or not? thank you can i check client is disposed or not? thank you can i check client is disposed or not? thank you can i check client is disposed or not? thank you

Answer (score 0):

First off -- there's no reason to spam the question several times.

But the answer is simply to use a try/catch for the ObjectDisposedException, this is pretty much the easiest way.

```cs
try 
{
    /* access myTcpClient */
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException)
{
    /* do some behaviour based on exception */
}
```

And that's all :)